# $item->children (http://......) in C#

Tags: php, asp.net

I'm working on converting a PHP Google calendar parser to .NET/C#. I'm not that familiar with PHP; I was having trouble understanding how this line works:

```
$gd = $item->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005')
```

It comes in part of a foreach loop:

```
$s = simplexml_load_file($feed); 

foreach ($s->entry as $item) {
    $gd = $item->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
    if ($gd->eventStatus->attributes()->value == $confirmed) {
?>
        <font size=+1><b>
            <?php print $item->title; ?>
        </b></font><br>..........
```

My main question is how does $item->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005') work? What does it do with the URL? Is there an equivalent in .Net or C#?

Comment: That's just XML parsing, and to understand how it works, reading the [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) would probably be a great place to start.

Comment: That's an XML namespace.  See LINQ to XML and the XNamespace class.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think PHP allows using strings inside indexers so what you're looking at would be similar to the following in C#:

```
var SomeObject = SomeDictionary["http://schemas.google/com/g/2005"];
```

Answer (score 1):

What it does is find the children of `<entry>` that match a particular namespace.

For example:

```
<doc xmlns:bla="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
...
<entry>
    <bla:test>hello</bla:test>
    <otherstuff>you can't see me</otherstuff>
</entry>
```

In your code example, it would match the child with `hello` as contents.

How that translates into C#, I'm not sure :)